# passing value obtained in one function to another function. C language

Tags: c

I am writing a program, that is encrypting a number, entered by user. Encryption steps are performed by functions, which I have to write. The problem is that I have to use value obtained in one function, in the next function. Here is what I am trying to do:
first function reads an integer. second adds 4 to every digit of that integer. and the problem is that how to use the integer that is entered in the first function, in the second function.

```
 void input(int *num)
{
  int numin;
  printf("Please enter an integer greater than 99999: ");
  scanf("%d", &numin);
  while (numin<99999)
    {
      printf("Incorrect input.\n");
      printf("Please enter an integer greater than 99999: ");
      scanf("%d", &numin);
    }    
  num=&numin;
  printf("The number entered is %d\n", numin);
  return;
}
int add4(int num)
{
  int a,b=1,numplus4;
  int i=-1;
  for (numplus4=0; b==0;)
    {
      a=num%10;
      b=num/10;
      num=b;
      a+=4;
      if (a>9)
    a-=10;
      i++;
      numplus4+=a*pow(10, i);
    }
  num=numplus4;
  printf("%d\n", num);
  return num;
}
```

I have googled on this topic: but all i got didnot help me, most of answers are for Javascripts, but I am using C.

Comment: You're experiencing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Comment: `for (numplus4=0; b==0;)` - you probably mean `b != 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually returning anything from the `input` function.

Instead of passing a pointer to the number being set (which you do not set correctly) you should use the `return` statement to return the value:

```
int input(void)
{
    ...

    return numin;
}
```

Then you can use it as this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int result = add4(input());
    printf("Result is %d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

---

The reason you don't return anything in your current function, is because in the `input` function the parameter `num` is local to that function. So any changes you made to it (like assigning to it) is lost when the function return.

What you *are* doing is potentially dangerous as it borders on undefined behaviour. You want to make the pointer point to a local variable, but when the function returns the memory where that local variable is stored is no longer valid to access.

You *can* use pointer arguments to return values though, this is what is called passing arguments by reference. But you don't assign *pointer* like you do, instead you use the *dereferencing* operator (unary `*`):

```
*num = numin;
```

For it to be valid though, you have to pass the address of an already allocated variable, like this:

```
int num;
input(&num);  /* Use the address-of operator to create a pointer */
```

However, I suggest using the solution in the first part of this answer, until you know more about pointers and how they work.

Comment: the problem is that I have to write function input in this way - having a type of void.

Comment: @EmiLazE Then see my modified answer.

Comment: ok. then how I will call integer stored in num, in my add4 function?

Comment: oh, i am sorry. i am very sleepy(it's 2am :D). i did not understand your answer from the first time. it worked :D :D :D

Answer (score 1):

You have to dereference the pointer in order to save the inputted value to the memory location pointed to by the pointer:

```
void input(int* num) {
    int numin;
    printf("Please enter an integer greater than 99999: ");
    scanf("%d", &numin);
    while (numin<99999)
    {
       printf("Incorrect input.\n");
       printf("Please enter an integer greater than 99999: ");
       scanf("%d", &numin);
   }    
  printf("The number entered is %d\n", numin);
  *num=numin;  // <-- This line needs the '*' at the beginning
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value obtained in one function can be used in the another function if the variable is declared as static variable.

Comment: Doesn't static just change the lifetime, not the visibility?